# `[Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber]` not returning anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have this little project to help me get used to Objective-C and iOS development, it is supposed to show quotes on the screen and change the quotes every 20 seconds or anytime the user presses a button. To achieve that I have this code so far:

```
-(void) CreateArray {
    Quotes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"Maybe, just once, someone will call me 'Sir' without adding, 'You're making a scene.'",
              @"You know, boys, a nuclear reactor is a lot like a woman. You just have to read the manual and press the right buttons.",
              @"When will I learn? The answer to life's problems aren't at the bottom of a bottle, they're on TV!",
              @"Son, when you participate in sporting events, it's not whether you win or lose: it's how drunk you get.",
              @"Please don't eat me! I have a wife and kids. Eat them!",
              @"Marriage is like a coffin and each kid is another nail.",
              @"Kids, you tried your best and you failed miserably. The lesson is, never try.",
              @"When I look at the smiles on all the children's faces, I just know they're about to jab me with something.",
              @"I want to share something with you: The three little sentences that will get you through life. Number 1: Cover for me. Number 2: Oh, good idea, Boss! Number 3: It was like that when I got here.",
              @"Oh, people can come up with statistics to prove anything, Kent. 14% of people know that.",
              @"Remember that postcard Grandpa sent us from Florida of that Alligator biting that woman's bottom? That's right, we all thought it was hilarious. But, it turns out we were wrong. That alligator was sexually harrassing that woman.",
              @"Kill my boss? Do I dare live out the American dream?",
              @"If something goes wrong at the plant, blame the guy who can't speak English.",
              @"Alcohol is a way of life, alcohol is my way of life, and I aim to keep it."];
}

-(void) nextQuote:(NSTimer *)timer {
    quoteNumber++;
    QuoteLabel.text = [Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber];
}

-(IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
    quoteNumber++;
    NSString *Quote = [Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber];
    QuoteLabel.text = Quote;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self selector:@selector(nextQuote:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

I can't really see any problems with this code, but so far I've had one pretty big problem: whenever the quote is supposed to change, the label just goes blank. I've tried using `NSLog` to see what is being returned by `[Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber]`, and it didn't log anything. I also tried using `Quotes[quoteNumber]`, but it wasn't different at all.

I am a beginner with Objective-C and iOS development, so this might have a very obvious solution, but I tried looking the web for it and couldn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: Show how `Quotes` is declared. Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint in `nextButton:` and `nextQuote:`. Are they called? Do the variables have the values you expect? And use standard naming conventions. Variables and methods should start with lowercase. Classes should begin with uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never called `CreateArray` so the `Quotes` array is always empty.

Few other things worth noting. Class names should start with a capital letter, method/properties should be a lower case letter.

Also with these methods:

```
-(void) nextQuote:(NSTimer *)timer {
    quoteNumber++;
    QuoteLabel.text = [Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber];
}

-(IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {
    quoteNumber++;
    NSString *Quote = [Quotes objectAtIndex: quoteNumber];
    QuoteLabel.text = Quote;
}
```

You'll eventually get index out of bounds because you're never resetting the `quoteNumber`. something like

```
if(quoteNumber % self.Quotes.count == 0){
  quoteNumber = 0;
}
```

Would reset it whenever the `quoteNumber` and the number of objects in your `Quotes` array is the same.

Lastly, what is `Quotes`? Is it a property? If so you should opt for something like overriding the getter

```
- (NSArray *)quotes
{
  if(!_quotes){
    _quotes = @[]; //Here is where you'd make your array with objects
}
```

That should get you up and running.

Comment: Thank you, about getting the index out of bounds, I was only using that expression to make sure that the problem was not on my previous expression. I created Quotes on the .h file with `NSArray * Quotes`, which, I understand, is not the best way to do it, is it?